# Which is the Fastest Memory, Cache memory or Register?

Tags: caching, memory, cpu-registers

I have searched everywhere and I am getting different answers every time.

Answer (score 0):

From a computer architecture point of view. Definely, register is the fastest. Second is the L1 cache memory(for CPU).
BTW, It will helpful if you show the reference link to your researched "everywhere", so that maybe i could help point out why there are the different opinion.